# How do i add my local git repo to my existing bitbucket repo

Tags: git, terminal, bitbucket

My local repo name exists here : `cd /Volumes/D/Website`

Repo Folder Name: Supro

My Bitbucket repo : `https://Suprodeep@bitbucket.org/Suprodeep/testlabs.git`

When i try to `git push` it says this:

```
supro@Homes-MacBook-Air Website % git push supro master           
*To https://bitbucket.org/Suprodeep/testlabs.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/Suprodeep/testlabs.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
supro@Homes-MacBook-Air Website %*
```

When i try to pull first then by:

```
git pull supro master --allow-unrelated-histories

*error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.*
```

Comment: "Exiting because of unfinished merge" -> you are in the middle of a merge. Abort or complete this merge first, then fetch or pull.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have unmerged changes. Try to commit everything in your repo and the pull:

```sh
# Check what's not committed
git status 
# Add everything if you have to, or individually depending on what you want
git add *
git commit
# Then pull
git pull supro master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

If you don't care about the merge. You can hard reset to `HEAD` and then pull

```sh
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull supro master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: In both the above cases it takes to me do this: I am a new bee terminal user and dont know what to do :

Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/Suprodeep/testlabs into HEAD
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit

Comment: Edit the file with your message then save it and quit the editor. After that you will have officially committed the merge.